# Lightning API not working

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, workbench

I am trying to use Lightning API in my salesforce org. I have followed [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightningapi.meta/lightningapi/lightning_api_get_started.htm) documentation provided by salesforce.
But I am getting this response.

[image]

```
Raw Response
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 07:08:17 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0oMpnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhIhduS2bxVLfzXsY="; max-age=86400; report-uri="https://calm-dawn-26291.herokuapp.com/hpkp-report/00D28000000bYxx";
Content-Security-Policy: referrer origin-when-cross-origin
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=QIUD3fFrRhSMBo_bdkZO9A;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 07-Oct-2017 07:08:17 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=128/15000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


[ {
  "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
  "message" : "The requested resource does not exist"
} ]
```

Comment: I have checked this on sendbox and personal free DE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will likely be an Summer '17 feature, which would imply it needs API version 40.0.

Try changing the `/v39.0/` out the in URL to `/v40.0/`.

Also, as per the [current documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightningapi.meta/lightningapi/lightning_api_get_started.htm), make sure you are calling the API against a Developer Edition org. It won't work on a sandbox.

> Lightning API is available as a Developer Preview in all DE orgs. To use the API in another type of org, contact Salesforce.

Also, see [Lightning API Name Changed to User Interface API](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_ui_name.htm).

> The User Interface API base URL has changed from /lapi to /ui-api.
>
> `https://{your_instance}.salesforce.com/services/data/v{api_version}/ui-api`

Finally, your URL shows the [006 keyprefix of an Opportunity](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html#006). Opportunity isn't currently on the [User Interface API Supported Objects](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_ui_objects.htm?edition=&impact=) list.

Comment: Can we use it in Winter '18 ?
Thanks!

Comment: @Kritik The User Interface API is [Generally Available in Winter '18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_api_ui.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The User Interface API base URL has changed from /lapi to /ui-api.

Try with this in [WorkBench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php)

> /services/data/v40.0/ui-api/record-ui/001R0000003GeJ1IAK

[Salesforce Summer ’17 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_ui_name.htm)